# Null Second Fundamental Form Expansion & Null Geodesic Congruence

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, differential-geometry, geodesics

I'm a mathematician delving into the world of physics and I've come across what seem to be two closely related concepts but I can't piece them together. I'm particularly interested in defining a trapped surface.

Suppose we have a submanifold $\Sigma$ embedded in our spacetime manifold $(M,g)$ with the induced metric. Let $K$ be an outward pointing, null normal vector field on $\Sigma$ such that $K(p) \in {\left(T_p\Sigma\right)}^{\perp}$ for all $p \in \Sigma$. Then we define the Null Second Fundamental Form of $\Sigma$ with respect to $K$ to be the bilinear form

$$\chi: T_p\Sigma \times T_p\Sigma \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$
$$\chi(X,Y)= g(Y, \nabla_XK)$$

where $\nabla$ represents the levi-civita connection on $M$. We of course are able to represent this as a matrix $\chi = \chi_{ij}$ and I believe the trace of this matrix will give us our expansion parameter $\theta$. This is what we require to be negative for our surface $\Sigma$ to be trapped.

Now, on the other hand I know that a trapped surface is one such that from within this surface, future-pointing, outgoing (and incoming) null geodesics are converging and thus are "coming back in on themselves". This makes sense conceptually. I understand geodesic congruences, and that this negative expansion is essentially a decrease in the cross sectional volume element of the congruence.

So we have two concepts of an expansion, both seem to define a trapped surface. But I'm unable to join these together. How do we related the decrease in the cross sectional volume element of a null geodesic congruence with the trace of the null second fundamental form? The null second fundamental form part makes sense to me mathematically, but not conceptually. The geodesic congruence makes sense conceptually, but not so much mathematically.

NB: As a mathematician, I'm not too concerned with physical technicalities, but if there are any major red flags in my wording then please feel free to point them out.